# Converting HTML to MJML?

Tags: html, mjml

I'm new to MJML and I'm wondering if it's possible to convert HTML to MJML? I've tried searching for answers but the results are always the opposite.

Comment: codedmails.com has many MJML - HTML templates. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
I guess your question is, "Is it possible to convert HTML to MJML automatically? Is there any tool for that?"
That is not possible. As far as I know, there is no such tool.

You can only manually "convert" HTML to MJML. Basically, that means you write MJML code that produces specified HTML output.

Comment: hmm. I have one html file which is converted from mjml but I don't have the source mjml file.  It would be helpful if there's some way to make it back to mjml.